# telegram python bot - birthday reminder

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

/edit: moving `today = date.today()` to every function updates the date and the script finally works.

I'm trying to add a functionality to my telegram-python-bot which is a birthday reminder. I can't figure it out why is not working. Actually, it works the first time the job runs but then the second time fails and so on.

Main code

```
from datetime import datetime, date, time
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, CallbackQueryHandler
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from events import *
import logging, telegram, pytz

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

TOKEN = 'my_token'

if __name__ == "__main__":
  updater = Updater(token=TOKEN, use_context=True)

  dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
  updater.start_polling()
  updater.start_polling(allowed_updates=[])
  
  j = updater.job_queue
  
  ####### birthdays ####### 
    
  time_birthdays_weekdays = time(14, 40, 00, 000000,tzinfo=pytz.timezone('America/Chicago')) 
  time_birthdays_weekend = time(11, 10, 00, 000000,tzinfo=pytz.timezone('America/Chicago')) 
  
  job_daily_birthday_weekdays = j.run_daily(birthday,time_birthdays_weekdays, days=(0, 1, 2, 3, 4))
  job_daily_birthday_weekend = j.run_daily(birthday,time_birthdays_weekend, days=(5, 6))
  
  ####### other events ####### 
  job_daily_other_events = j.run_daily(other_events, time_birthdays_weekdays, days=(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
  
  ####### Hollidays ####### 
  t_holli = time (00, 10, 00, 000000,tzinfo=pytz.timezone('America/Chicago')) 
  job_daily_holli = j.run_daily(holli,t_holli,days=(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
```

And then the file called "events" with several dictionaries containing the info about each person and a function called by the main bot that checks for dictionary values and keys

```
    from datetime import datetime, date, time
    from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, CallbackQueryHandler
    
    import logging, telegram, pytz, sys
    
    chat_id_eventos = some_number
    today = date.today()

    dic_person_number1 = {
        'name' : 'Person',
        'lastname' : 'Number1',
        'day' : '11',
        'month' : '7',
        'telegram_id' : '@person1',    

    
    dic_person_number2 = {
        'name' : 'Person',
        'lastname' : 'Number2',
        'day' : '12',
        'month' : '7',
        'telegram_id' : '@person2',
        }
    
    def birthday(context):
        for i in dic_person_number1, dic_person_number2:
            if str(today.day) in i.get("day") and str(today.month) in i.get("month"):
                context.bot.send_message(chat_id = chat_id_eventos, 
                                    text='¡¡¡Today it's ' + i['nombre'] + ' '+ i['apellido'] + 'birthday!!!. )
```

And the same with other functions that remind of other dates. I use the for to avoid using a lot of ifs, so in this way the idea is to look into all dicts for matching values defined in the if

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: "but then the second time fails and so on." - what exactly do you mean by that? do you get an error message? does the job simply not run? have you checked your error logs?

Comment: It does run but it duplicates the last message, i dont see an error on the console. I've tried in a separate script without the telegram bot part and it matches day and month and prints the correct message. But when i add it to the bot as a scheduled function it starts failing.

Comment: Well ... i think i know where the problem is. I'm testing the solution these days as i figured out today so in a couple of days after a few jobs triggered i'll be able to confirm it. today = date.today() has to be in every function if not, it is only being configured the first time the script runs and never again so it's not being updated. Kind of silly but i think that's it.